# Delete a QBChatDialog for all users?

Tags: ios, quickblox

I'm using QuickBlox to allow chat in my application. At one point, I've come across a requirement for which I've to delete the existing private chat dialog.

Below is the code given in QuickBlox site which deletes a dialog for current user and not for other users.

```
[QBRequest deleteDialogWithID:@"54fda689535c125b0700bbfa" successBlock:^(QBResponse *responce) {

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", response.error);
}];
```

This works fine ! However what if I want to delete it for each of the users? Any luck ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickblox uses the same behavior as Skype. You can delete a dialog only for you, not for others. You can't change this behavior.

But you can use Custom Objects and store there a table with dialog ID and permission "allow", "deny".
And for other users check this table before you can send a message.

Answer (score 1):

I guess we can add such functionality in future

something like this:

```
[QBRequest forceDeleteDialogWithID: ]
```

and only dialog's creator will be able to do it

What do you think?

Comment: Sounds good ! Only dialog owner or admin of the group can do this.